# How NonClustered Index works in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, b-tree, non-clustered-index

I have a question, related to DB theory:

Let's assume that we have table with 3 columns: `[PersonID], [PersonName], [PersonAge]`.

We know that when we have a nonclustered index by one column, SQL Server orders table data in accordance with specified column and build B+ tree from it. And when we need to find the row using such an index, SQL Server scans the B++ tree by comparing one atomic data object (`int` or `string`, for example). That is clear, how non-clustered index works and find data when we build it by one column (suppose `[PersonName]`), but what if we create non-clustered index by 2 columns: `[PersonName]` and `[PersonAge]`?

I understand, that during sorting criterion with main importance will be `[PersonName]` and if several records have it same, than they would be sorted by `[PersonAge]`. But how physically SQL Server would process the B++ tree, based on this index?

How it will use such tree when it should execute query like

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.Person 
WHERE [PersonName] = 'Bob' AND [PersonAge] = 45
```

Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nonclustered index will be pretty much the same as with just one column - but each index entry in the B++ navigation tree will have **two** column values `(PersonName, PersonAge)`.

Since both columns are comparable, a clearly defined ordering will be applied - first by `PersonName`, then by `PersonAge` - so your navigation tree items would look something like this (if looked at as a flat list):

```
Alice,42
Alice,57
Andrew,31
Anthony,23
...
...
Bertrand,48
Bob,34
Bob,39
Bob,44 
Bob,45
Bob,58
......
Zachary,19
```

When you run your query

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.Person 
WHERE [PersonName] = 'Bob' AND [PersonAge] = 45
```

then SQL Server will navigate the B++ navigation tree - first looking at the `PersonName`, until it finds all occurrences of `Bob`, and then it scans all Bob's to find the one you're looking for (or maybe it doesn't find it).

Comment: Thank you an advance. So, if I understand correct, SQL Server finds ALL the records where [PersonName] is 'Bob'(seek operation) and then it will scan each of those record's and comparing with 45 (Age value)? If it is so, what  sense of ordering by [PersonAge] parameter? Which profit it gives for us?

Comment: @Alex44: if you *don't* have the `PersonAge` in the index - then how could SQL Server find the *correct* Bob? It couldn't - it would have to take **all** Bobs it finds, go to the actual data page (in the clustered index leaf level) and inspect the `PersonAge` attribute there. That would results in several very expensive **Key Lookup** operations and thus would significantly hurt performance